# Finding the Average in a sequence of number in c while ignoring the negative numbers in the sequence

Tags: c, average

I have to write a C program that reads a sequence of integers (positive, negative, or zero) and calculate the average of the **positive integers only**. 
If there are no positive numbers, you should display the following statement followed by a new line
**No positive numbers!**

Here is my code, I just need help with how to ignore the negative numbers in the input sequence.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int num;  //number of elements
    int i;
    int sequence[100];  //numeber if sequence
    int sum = 0.0;            //sum if the sequence
    float avg;          // the average

    printf("Enter the number of number in the sequence:\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while (num < 0 || sequence[num] < 0) {
        printf("No positine numbers!\n");
    }

    printf("Enter the sequence:\n");
    for (i=0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &sequence[i]);
        sum += sequence[i];
    }

    avg = (float) sum / num;
    printf("Average is %.2f\n", avg);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: A hint for starters: You do not need to store the full sequence of numbers, just add up the positive ones and keep a counter tracking how many you added. Divide after that.

Comment: you never break the while loop once you enter it.  "No positine numbers!\n" spammed forever.  you dont initialize any of your variables when you declare them, so you use squence[num] before its initialized.  but to answer your question, dont add sum += sequence[i] when sequence[i] is <= 0.

Comment: Please explain each line of your coding attempt, by adding a comment. It is very unclear what your thinking is. What is the idea of `sequence[num] < 0`? Where in  your code is anything related to "only positive numbers"?

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
while (num < 0 || sequence[num] < 0) {
```

you are testing `sequence[num]` before you have written any values to the array, and the test of `num` should be `num <= 0` since if there are zero values, there are also no positive values.  You can only decide that there are no positive values after you have entered them all.

The array `sequence` is unnecessary - you can simply accumulate the positive values to `sum` and discard them, maintaining a count of valid values.  The avoids any buffer overrun issues also.

`sum` is an `int`, but you have unnecessarily initialised it with a `double`.

Your average calculation:

```
avg = (float) sum / num ;
```

is incorrect since `num` includes negative values - you need a separate count of valid values contributing to the average (unless the intent is to treat all negative values as zero).

Another issue is that you have not validated the input matched the format specifier.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter the number of number in the sequence:\n");
    int num = 0 ;
    int check = scanf( "%d", &num ) ;

    int positive_count = 0 ;
    int sum = 0 ;
    if( check != 0 && num >= 0 )
    {
        printf( "Enter the sequence:\n" ) ;

        int i = 0 ;
        while( i < num ) 
        {
            int value = 0 ;
            check = scanf( "%d", &value ) ;
            if( check != 0 )
            {
                i++ ;
                if( value >= 0 )
                {
                    positive_count++ ;
                    sum += value ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if( positive_count != 0 )
    {
        float avg = (float) sum / positive_count ;

        printf( "Average is %.2f\n", avg ) ;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "No positive numbers!\n" ) ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the average of the positive numbers, you should use a different variable than num for your final avg calculation.

I would do something like this:

```
    int PositiveNumCount = 0;
    float avg;   
    for (i=0; i < num; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &sequence[i]);
        if(sequence[i] > 0){ sum += sequence[i]; PositiveNumCount++;}
    }
    avg = (float) sum / PositiveNumCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `sequence[num]` may refer to an entry beyond the end of the array which has undefined behavior, and otherwise reads from an uninitalized array, which has undefined behavior too. Just remove this test completely as it is useless.
- you do not need to store the numbers read, just read them ne at a time into a temporary variable and only add and count the positive values.
- you should test the return value of `scanf` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num;           // max number of values to read
    int count = 0;     // number of positive values
    double sum = 0.0;  // sum if the sequence
    double avg;        // the average

    printf("Enter the number of number in the sequence:\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &num) == 1 && num > 0) {
        printf("Enter the sequence:\n");
        while (num-- > 0) {
            int temp;
            if (scanf("%d", &temp) != 1)
                break;
            if (temp >= 0) {
                sum += temp;
                count++;
            }
        }
        avg = sum / count;
        printf("Average is %.2f\n", avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("Enter the sequence:\n");
for (i=0; i < num; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &sequence[i]);
    if(sequeunce[i] > 0){ //This if statement is what your looking for, but there are several other problems in your code.  GL!
        sum += sequence[i];
    }
}
```

The above if statement is what the OP was asking for: "Here is my code, I just need help with how to ignore the negative numbers in the input sequence."

There are many issues with his posted code, including using variables before they are initialized and infinite looping paths.  This is the shortest answer to his question.

Comment: This will give a wrong average, since you still have to track how many positive numbers you have added

Comment: Would you like to improve this code-only answer by adding some explanation?

Comment: From the OPs only question: "Here is my code, I just need help with how to ignore the negative numbers in the input sequence."  This code is riddled with issues...

Comment: @Yunnosch I have clarified my response, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Pointing out shortcomings and giving the shortest possible answer is not the same as a helpful answer and not the explanation to improve the answer either.

Comment: By me, for the reasons you mentioned @Yunnosch

Comment: @Yunnosch well thanks for clarifiying that.  I put the list of issues with the OPs source as the second comment to his question.

Comment: @ctx Fair is fair. And being open about it deserves respect in my opinion.

Comment: @Ctx He asked SPECIFICALLY where he needed help.  he didnt ask SO to finish his homework for him.  My answer is legitimately what the OP was requesting, but feel free to downvote me anyways.  Clearly this is a homework assignment and a learning experience, leaving the other issues in there is beneficial to his debugging efforts so he can LEARN on his own.

Comment: Giving only what OP asks for, with little explanation, is not the same as a helpful answer, especially not from point of view of every other future reader.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.